# Find value in dataframe row - create new column highlighting next row match

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a value in a Pandas dataframe row and create a new column highlighting if the next row is a match.  So for the following example:

```
rng = pd.DataFrame( {'test_1': ['A', 'A','A', 'A', 'B','B', 'A' , 'A', 'A', 'A','A' , 'A', 'A', 'A',]},  index = pd.date_range('4/2/2014', periods=14, freq='BH'))
reg
```

The rows == B on 2014-04-02 13:00:00 and 2014-04-02 14:00:00 so there is a match:

```
    test_1
2014-04-02 09:00:00 A
2014-04-02 10:00:00 A
2014-04-02 11:00:00 A
2014-04-02 12:00:00 A
2014-04-02 13:00:00 B
2014-04-02 14:00:00 B
2014-04-02 15:00:00 A
2014-04-02 16:00:00 A
2014-04-03 09:00:00 A
2014-04-03 10:00:00 A
2014-04-03 11:00:00 C
2014-04-03 12:00:00 A
2014-04-03 13:00:00 D
2014-04-03 14:00:00 D
```

so the new column should be as follows:

```
B_Matches
    2014-04-02 09:00:00 0
    2014-04-02 10:00:00 0
    2014-04-02 11:00:00 0
    2014-04-02 12:00:00 0
    2014-04-02 13:00:00 0
    2014-04-02 14:00:00 1
    2014-04-02 15:00:00 0
    2014-04-02 16:00:00 0
    2014-04-03 09:00:00 0
    2014-04-03 10:00:00 0
    2014-04-03 11:00:00 0
    2014-04-03 12:00:00 0
    2014-04-03 13:00:00 0
    2014-04-03 14:00:00 0
```

I will then be doing the same for C, D etc in other columns.  I am basically trying to find times when a certain condition is seen and the next period is the same and I will be doing a count() on this column to see how frequently the next period matches.  Please also show any other ways of doing this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a func that takes your value and returns whether any rows meets your condition, this will work for any value you pass, the boolean series is then cast to `int` so it converts `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively:

```
In [220]:
def func(val):
    return ((rng['test_1'] == val) & (rng['test_1'].shift() == val)).astype(int)
​
func('B')

Out[220]:
2014-04-02 09:00:00    0
2014-04-02 10:00:00    0
2014-04-02 11:00:00    0
2014-04-02 12:00:00    0
2014-04-02 13:00:00    0
2014-04-02 14:00:00    1
2014-04-02 15:00:00    0
2014-04-02 16:00:00    0
2014-04-03 09:00:00    0
2014-04-03 10:00:00    0
2014-04-03 11:00:00    0
2014-04-03 12:00:00    0
2014-04-03 13:00:00    0
2014-04-03 14:00:00    0
Freq: BH, Name: test_1, dtype: int32

In [222]:
func('A')

Out[222]:
2014-04-02 09:00:00    0
2014-04-02 10:00:00    1
2014-04-02 11:00:00    1
2014-04-02 12:00:00    1
2014-04-02 13:00:00    0
2014-04-02 14:00:00    0
2014-04-02 15:00:00    0
2014-04-02 16:00:00    1
2014-04-03 09:00:00    1
2014-04-03 10:00:00    1
2014-04-03 11:00:00    1
2014-04-03 12:00:00    1
2014-04-03 13:00:00    1
2014-04-03 14:00:00    1
Freq: BH, Name: test_1, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks again EdChum.  I will use this across different df columns so modified slightly to `def func_match(df_in,val):
    return ((df_in == val) & (df_in.shift() == val)).astype(int)`.